# docker-machine create -driver virtualbox vps1 can't run properly

Tags: docker, docker-machine

My system is Ubuntu version 20. I already installed Docker Desktop. Now I would like to create Docker Host but it can't do. Below I reproduce my error

Step 1: docker-machine create -driver virtualbox vps1

Step 2: Command run to "Waiting for an IP..." and No more response

Could you please help me for this issue? Thanks so much for your advise

[image]

Comment: Do you need to do either of these things; or can you uninstall Docker Desktop and Docker Machine, and use the [Docker Engine](https://docs.docker.com/engine/) directly on your host system?